# When I don't use the go keyword a function doesn't work

Tags: go, concurrency

In this function you can see that I use the go keyword.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan string)
    go findGreatestDivisor(4, c)
    for i := 0; i <= 1; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-c)
    }
}

func findGreatestDivisor(num float64, c chan string) {
    var counter float64 = 10000
    for i := 9999; i > 0; i-- {
        if math.Mod(num, counter) == 0 {
            fmt.Println("Check..", math.Mod(4, 1))
            c <- fmt.Sprintf("%f is divisble by %d", num, i)
        }
        counter--
    }

}
```

It works. It gives me the largest integer. But now I get curious and delete the go keyword where I called the function here

```
go findGreatestDivisor(4,c)
```

When i just do

```
findGreatestDivisor(4,c)
```

it gives me the error

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]: main.findGreatestDivisor(0x4010000000000000,
0xc82001a0c0)
       /home/ubuntu/workspace/test.go:21 +0x37c main.main()
       /home/ubuntu/workspace/test.go:10 +0x61 exit status 2
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Send statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements)
>
> A send statement sends a value on a channel. The channel expression
>   must be of channel type, the channel direction must permit send
>   operations, and the type of the value to be sent must be assignable to
>   the channel's element type.
>
> ```
> SendStmt = Channel "<-" Expression .
> Channel  = Expression .
> ```
>
> Both the channel and the value expression are evaluated before
>   communication begins. Communication blocks until the send can proceed.
>   A send on an unbuffered channel can proceed if a receiver is ready. A
>   send on a buffered channel can proceed if there is room in the buffer.
>   A send on a closed channel proceeds by causing a run-time panic. A
>   send on a nil channel blocks forever.
>
> ```
> ch <- 3  // send value 3 to channel ch
> ```

In `findGreatestDivisor`

```
c := make(chan string)
findGreatestDivisor(4,c)
```

you try to send on the unbuffered channel `c`

```
c <- fmt.Sprintf("%f is divisble by %d", num, i)
```

but communication blocks until the send can proceed. A send on an unbuffered channel can proceed if a receiver is ready. There is no receiver ready.

The receives on channel `c`

```
fmt.Println(<-c)
```

won't be ready until after you return from `findGreatestDivisor`. That's too late.

Comment: Ok peter! Thanks a lot! Your the best